# how to get Identity Value for each iteration bulk insert

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, primary-key, ef-bulkinsert

```
List< IletisimLog> bulkInsertIletisimLog = new List<IletisimLog>();
//there are 1000 values in the array of paramaters
foreach (var kId in paramaters)
{     
    var iletisimLogInsert = new IletisimLog()
    {
        KullaniciID = kId.KullaniciId,
        EklendigiTarih = DateTime.Now,
        GonderildigiTarih = DateTime.Now,
        BilgilendirmeTurID = bilgilendirmeturId,
    };
    bulkInsertIletisimLog.Add(iletisimLogInsert);

}
_iLetisimLogService.BulkInsertRange(bulkInsertIletisimLog);
```

There are 1000 records registered in the database. How to get the primary key value for each record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you loop through the Entities to add them to the database, if there is a primary key on there, the Id that is assigned to each will be reflected in the object.

```
List< IletisimLog> bulkInsertIletisimLog = new List<IletisimLog>();
//there are 1000 values in the array of paramaters
foreach (var kId in paramaters)
{     
    var iletisimLogInsert = new IletisimLog()
    {
        KullaniciID = kId.KullaniciId,
        EklendigiTarih = DateTime.Now,
        GonderildigiTarih = DateTime.Now,
        BilgilendirmeTurID = bilgilendirmeturId,
    };
    bulkInsertIletisimLog.Add(iletisimLogInsert);    
}

_iLetisimLogService.BulkInsertRange(bulkInsertIletisimLog);

foreach (var inserted in bulkInsertIletisimLog)
{
    // Get the ID of the inserted object
    var newId = inserted.Id;
}
```

Assuming primary key value on your object is called `Id`.